# Parallelization of Genetic Algorithm Slowed Algorithm Significantly. Why would this be?

Tags: java, performance, parallel-processing, genetic-algorithm

I've written a genetic algorithm and in an attempt to optimize its performance, I decided to parallelize the fitness testing for individuals. To see what kind of change this made in my algorithm, I redid a test run I had done before the parallelization where I tested the GA's performance for growing population sizes.

The parallel version of the GA actually took roughly 50% longer than the original version. I realize that sometimes the overhead of the parallelization can actually take more time than it saves, but I doubt that that should apply in this situation - my fitness test is finding the global minimum of a Sheckel's Foxholes function ( http://extreme.adorio-research.org/download/mvf/html/node51.html ), and my population sizes range from 10 to 1000. I would expect that in parallelizing 1000 executions of sheckel's foxholes the time saved would greatly outweigh the overhead of parallelization.

So my question is: why would the parallelization have slowed down the algorithm (and so significantly)?

For the record, I'm coding in Java and I'm parallelizing using a CountDownLatch that waits for all threads (fitness tests) to execute before continuing on.

Comment: What CPU chip are you using?  If it's an old single core, parallelizing won't help.  That said, I've found that a good paralleization on an Intel I3 does give nearly 2X performance as one would expect.

Comment: Ha, the thought that it was being limited by hardware had crossed my mind. I'm on an older dual-core, so I realize that the parellelization isn't going to be as effective as it would be were I on a more powerful machine, but it should still be faster than just a serial exectuion. Also, I'm just programming it on the dual-core, it's actually going to be moved to an octocore when I'm done.

Comment: Sounds like you should be getting some speed increase.  O.K., two more "obvious" questions.  Are you doing much I/O?  And is there any synchronization/locking on resources?

Comment: There's no IO going on at all, and there's no synchronization/locking on resources - the fitness tests are contained within an Individual class object, so they're all independent of each other. The only way that the threads are related to each other is that they all share the same countdownlatch, which is simply used to find out when they've all completed and then move forward in the algorithm.

Comment: Are you running 100s of threads at once?  Or something reasonable, like 4-8 threads at a time, e.g. using an ExecutorService?

Comment: I'm running one thread per Individual in the Population. I ran a bunch of trials with growing population sizes between 10 to 1000, meaning I'm asking for 10 to 1000 threads simultaneously. I understand that this is extreme, but I'm doing this for testing purposes - I wanted to see the behavior of the algorithm with the paralellization in place. I figured there'd be a backlog of threads that the processor would just eventually work through, but that, again, that overhead would be negated by the parellelization.

Comment: Creating a new thread is an expensive operation. If you re-create the threads in each generation you'd be begging for slow performance. You should only use a reasonable amount of threads (depending on the amount of cores) and reuse the threads that you create.

Comment: @DonAndre is right.  That's another thing that ExecutorService etc... will manage for you, reusing a pool of Threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out what the problem was - I had assumed that my fitness test was taking long enough that parellelization would be worthwhile, but it totally was not. I padded the fitness test, made it artificially long (it's just a test fitness test I'm using to monitor the performance of the GA anyway), and I now see a significant difference in the execution time - a growing population size now results in extending the execution time by 1000s of a second, instead of 10s of seconds. And I should point out that that's before implementing the Executor, as has been recommended.

Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Based upon your comments, it seems like you are doing things fairly reasonably, except perhaps for the number of threads.  But you mention that you are using a CountDownLatch gets me thinking...

I would strongly suggest that instead of your own code, you use an `ExecutorService/Executors` for the parallelization.  Make your class a `Callable`, create a bunch of them, and call invokeAll().  That way highly trained (not sure if they were highly paid) experts did most of the coding.

With `Executors`, it is simple to control the maximum number of threads.  You can call `Runtime.availableProcessors()` to get a first pass at how many threads to run at a time, then do some testing and tuning.

EDIT: Just posted an [introduction to converting an algorithm to use ExecutorService.](http://flyingspaniel.blogspot.com/2012/06/how-to-parallelize-your-algorithm-with.html) Enjoy, and comments/feedback welcome.

Comment: Hmmmmmm, seems like a reasonable exception, though I'm always hesitant to implement anything until I've familiarized myself with it first. I can definitely google Executors, but as you're suggesting it, do you have any recommended reading I could look at?

Comment: Maybe I'll make a blog entry and send you a link, but the safer bet is to spend a bit if money on the book _Java Concurrency in Practice_ by Goetz et. al.

Comment: So after doing some reading, I definitely think an Executor is the way to go - being able to simply create the threads at the beginning of the population and reuse them every generation would CERTAINLY save me a ton in performance. And, for anyone interested reading this thread in the future, I found this great blog post that was very helpful in understanding how Executors worked: http://www.softwareengineeringsolutions.com/blogs/2010/07/21/implementing-thread-pools-using-java-executors/

Answer (score 1):

Okay, the answer is that it didn't parallelize as much as you thought it should.  The question is "why?" and the answer will be difficult to achieve without a look at the code.  but there are some obvious places to look:

- make sure (you're gonna hate this one) that you're using the right entry point for Thread.  One way to guarantee that your threads will serialize and not tell you a thing is to call the `run()` method instead of the `start()` method.  It sounds silly but I've been bitten by this.
- make sure, using eg jconsole, that the threads are running concurrently at all.  If not, you've got an unexpected lock on something.
- check what you synchronize on. Check the collection classes you're using.  Some of them aren't thread-safe at all, and some of them are thread-safe because they've got internal synchronization.  Any Collection class that's shared among threads is a possible miscreant.
- If nothing leaps out with that, walk through the code execution on paper with a colleague and hand-write out the threads.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try your suggestions out.